# Stream audio from Android to Ustream

Tags: android, audio-streaming

Is it possible? Are there any public libraries which allow me to send live audio stream from the device to the Ustream server.

Comment: Any reason why not to use the UStream Android app?

Comment: I want the user to stay inside my app which provides plenty of features. Streaming to ustream will be just an addition